# Search for ID Key Value in Json Array and add Key with Values to Object array

Tags: node.js, json

I have Json array with two objects, in Json Array with two objects i have array with multiple objects in attachments.vaAttachments.

filename ist unique:

How can I search for specific values (attachments.vaAttachments.filename === 123456.pdf) if true add Key to object (name of key fileBase64) and value is "sahduidBASE64CODEsahuidhsauipdhasuiphd"

This is what i have now:

```
[{
"im": {
    "materialNumber": "A0009",
    "countryKey": "DE",
    "createdDate": "2022-03-09"
},
"attachments": {
    "vaAttachments": [
        {
            "filename": "123456.pdf",
            "originalFilename": "Sample.pdf",
            "createdAt": "2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z",

        },
        {
            "filename": "987654.pdf",
            "originalFilename": "Sample.pdf",
            "createdAt": "2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z"
        }
    ]
}
},
{
"im": {
    "materialNumber": "A0010",
    "countryKey": "DE",
    "createdDate": "2022-03-09"
},
"attachments": {
    "vaAttachments": [
        {
            "filename": "656565.pdf",
            "originalFilename": "Sample.pdf",
            "createdAt": "2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z"
        },
        {
            "filename": "753357.pdf",
            "originalFilename": "Sample.pdf",
            "createdAt": "2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z"
        }
    ]
}
}]
```

This is what i would like to have:

```
[{
"im": {
    "materialNumber": "A0009",
    "countryKey": "DE",
    "createdDate": "2022-03-09"
},
"attachments": {
    "vaAttachments": [
        {
            "filename": "123456.pdf",
            "originalFilename": "Sample.pdf",
            "createdAt": "2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z"
            "fileBase64": "sahduidBASE64CODEsahuidhsauipdhasuiphd" 
        },
        {
            "filename": "987654.pdf",
            "originalFilename": "Sample.pdf",
            "createdAt": "2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z"
        }
    ]
}
},
{
"im": {
    "materialNumber": "A0010",
    "countryKey": "DE",
    "createdDate": "2022-03-09"
},
"attachments": {
    "vaAttachments": [
        {
            "filename": "656565.pdf",
            "originalFilename": "Sample.pdf",
            "createdAt": "2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z"
        },
        {
            "filename": "753357.pdf",
            "originalFilename": "Sample.pdf",
            "createdAt": "2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z"
        }
    ]
}
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array.forEach` for the same, you can read about it in this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Also here you can use this function for the same:

```
const searchFunction = (arr, key) => {
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    const {
      attachments: { vaAttachments = [] }
    } = element
    vaAttachments.forEach((item) => {
      const { filename = '' } = item
      if (filename === key) {
        item.fileBase64 = 'sahduidBASE64CODEsahuidhsauipdhasuiphd'
      }
    })
  })
}

searchFunction(jsonArray, '123456.pdf')
console.log('jsonArray:', JSON.stringify(jsonArray))
```

Try and running it yourself:

```js
const jsonArray = [
  {
    im: {
      materialNumber: 'A0009',
      countryKey: 'DE',
      createdDate: '2022-03-09'
    },
    attachments: {
      vaAttachments: [
        {
          filename: '123456.pdf',
          originalFilename: 'Sample.pdf',
          createdAt: '2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z'
        },
        {
          filename: '987654.pdf',
          originalFilename: 'Sample.pdf',
          createdAt: '2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    im: {
      materialNumber: 'A0010',
      countryKey: 'DE',
      createdDate: '2022-03-09'
    },
    attachments: {
      vaAttachments: [
        {
          filename: '656565.pdf',
          originalFilename: 'Sample.pdf',
          createdAt: '2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z'
        },
        {
          filename: '753357.pdf',
          originalFilename: 'Sample.pdf',
          createdAt: '2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

const searchFunction = (arr, key) => {
  arr.forEach((element) => {
    const {
      attachments: { vaAttachments = [] }
    } = element
    vaAttachments.forEach((item) => {
      const { filename = '' } = item
      if (filename === key) {
        item.fileBase64 = 'sahduidBASE64CODEsahuidhsauipdhasuiphd'
      }
    })
  })
}

searchFunction(jsonArray, '123456.pdf')
console.log('jsonArray:', jsonArray)
```

Comment: There's one thing I don't like about this: The function returns a value, which makes it look as if it's a clone of the original structure when in fact the original has been mutated. I think that's a bad style of doing things, since other developers might write code on the assumption that `jsonArray` has not changed. You should either (a) mutate the original and return nothing or (b) return a deep clone with the required change.

Comment: @DavidKnipe I have updated the confusing part, now i am mutating the original array so that people wont get confused about the mutation part.

Comment: try running the code, i have already mentioned in the code for adding key and value pairs. If you run it, you can see the `fileBase64` will get added in `123456.pdf` filename.

Comment: @Ashishssoni
Tnx a lot! Can you pls tell me what is solution if i only have one Json object not array like:   {
    im: {
      materialNumber: 'A0009',
      countryKey: 'DE',
      createdDate: '2022-03-09'
    },
    attachments: {
      vaAttachments: [
        {
          filename: '123456.pdf',
          originalFilename: 'Sample.pdf',
          createdAt: '2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z'
        },
        {
          filename: '987654.pdf',
          originalFilename: 'Sample.pdf',
          createdAt: '2022-03-09T14:50:55.325Z'
        }
      ]
    }
  },

Comment: @Ashishssoni I think i found it, i modify your code it looks like: const searchFunction = (jsonArray, key) => {
  jsonArray.attachments.vaAttachments.forEach((item) => {
    const { filename = "" } = item;
    if (filename === key) {
      item.fileBase64 = "sahduidBASE64CODEsahuidhsauipdhasuiphd";
    }
  });
};

Comment: yes, thats also right. It will work

Comment: @Ashishssoni you are the best, tnx a lot. one more question :) how can i use searchFunction(jsonArray, '123456.pdf') with await?  await Promise.all([
         searchFunction(jsonArray, '123456.pdf')
        ]); is this right?

Comment: @user1862965 there is no need to use await since its a simple synchronous function, but if you want to use it anyway then you can do `await searchFunction(jsonArray, '123456.pdf') ` or if you want run multiple functions you can do something like  `await Promise.all([ searchFunction(jsonArray, '123456.pdf'), searchFunction(jsonArray, '656565.pdf') ])`.